# DTOs and object graphs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm making an Angular2 SPA with a webAPI REST service that exposes an EntityFramework model.

The quickest way to get going is to load up a big object graph in a single controller action and pass out a big blob of JSON to the client, which can then split it up as it walks the object graph.

Is it considered better practice to build API actions for each object in the object graph and have the JS client pull the graph piecemeal as required?

The piecemeal approach requires many more controllers and actions and, correspondingly, angular services, i.e., more work! Do I need to just grasp the nettle and get on with it?

Comment: What do you mean by a big object graph? How often will it be retrieved from a server? What are you trying to model with this object graph?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends whether your are using Entity Framework in connected scenarios or in disconnected scenarios. Regarding your case, you are using Entity framework in disconnected scenarios, which mean that `DBContext` doesn't attach to object graph all the time, because you get the data from database, send it to the client and then close the `context`. For me, I would recommend to use divide your controllers and actions for each `POCO` or `DTO` because this will help you to maintain and attach each object individually rather than maintain the whole object graph at once. The problem will start to appear when you start editing or manipulating your entities because in disconnected scenarios you never know which object has been edited or deleted or added in a big object graph. However, you should maintain and manipulate each change in client side directly to the sever to reflect that update.

I don't know if this answers your question, but if you need any further explanation or code sample. please let me know.

Comment: It had occurred to me that when I come to write an editor for the big object that round-tripping the whole object graph will be nasty; one will want to CRUD individual items.

I think, yes, it needs to be one controller wit CRUD for each POCO.

Comment: ya, it happens to me also. because of that I ending writing each POCO a controller and call each controller with each immediate change in client. Please if you consider my answer is useful or helpful, don't forget to vote up. Thank you.

Comment: I reckon I can deal with the controllers and TypeScript versions of the POCOs with a T4 or two...

Comment: you can use T4 for creating templates, and if you are using .NET Web API, you can use scaffolding templates. For more information on how to use T4, please refer to this article for one of my coworkers: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1318/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-t4

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make one backend action for one angular2 page-level component. User shouldn't wait for extra data loads, only data that needed on this page.